# $f$ is a 4th degree polynomial and $f(-0.2)=2.226, f(-0.1)=2.460, f(1)=3.004, f(0.2)=3.320$. Find $f'(0)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

$f$ is a 4<sup>th</sup> degree polynomial and $f(-0.2)=2.226, f(-0.1)=2.460, f(1)=3.004, f(0.2)=3.320$. Find $f'(0)$

My attempt:

Let $$f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$$
then
\begin{align*}
2.226&=a(0.2)^4+b(-0.2)^3+c(0.2)^2+d(-0.2)+e\\
2.460&=a(-0.1)^4+b(-0.1)^3+c(-0.1)^2+d(-0.1)+e\\
3.004&=a+b+c+d+e\\
3.320&=a(0.2)^4+b(0.2)^3+c(0.2)^2+d(0.2)+e\\
\end{align*}
Is there any good ways to approach these equation?

Comment: As written, $f'(0)$ can be made to be anything. Those four points do not define the fourth degree polynomial.

Comment: This is one of those ugly problems

Comment: I believe it should be $f(0.1)$, not $f(1)$. Then it would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating $f$ and substituting zero, you find that you only need to find the value of $d$ from your linear system.